# What causes the stems of sunchokes to turn red and lower leaves to die?

Tags: diagnosis, sunchoke

The bottom leaves of my sunchokes are beginning to die in tall grass, and a reddish color (with a small bubble that looks like a boil from the long stems that come out) is going up the main stem on one of the plants.

Does that mean I should dig them up, cut back on the water, or something else?

finally was able to get some images of it from someone:

[image: sunchoke red stem]
[image: sunchoke red stem 2]

Comment: Hi! Would you please post a few pictures of your sunchokes? The whole plant would be good, and especially something that shows the bubble that looks like a boil. That way we can see what you mean, which will probably make it easier to get you some good answers!  Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a smart phone, and it would look funny taking a picture with a laptop so I tried to describe it as best I could.

Comment: Use a digital camera. It's a good idea to track the growth of your plants with pictures

Comment: I don't have one

Answer (score 2):

Harvest when all the leaves have died back and after your first frost as that makes them sweeter. I left mine in the ground until I needed them which was late autumn, but some people leave them in the ground in winter as well. They'll keep better in the ground then out.

Comment: can you please review the answer again?